# How to plot or visualise multivariate D-vine copulas in R

Tags: r

I would like to plot D-vine copulas tree (at least tree 1) in R. I only found this function CDVineTreePlot that seems to do the job but there are some errors and the results cannot be generated.

`CDVineTreePlot(data, familyset = c(1:4,7,9,14), family = 136, type=2, tree=1)`

The error is "Dimension has to be at least 2."  My data is a matrix. Not sure where it's wrong. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: it says in the vignette, family needs to be : d*(d-1)/2 vector of pair-copula families with values, where d is number of columns, in short ncol(data)

Comment: can you try dd = ncol(U)*(ncol(U)-1)/2; CDVineTreePlot(data,family = rep(1,dd), type=2, tree=1)

Comment: it works perfectly when i used family=rep(1,dd) as your suggestion! Thank you very much. I now tried to adjust the position of the node by adding the parameter interactive = TRUE. however, it does not allow to adjust the position. So just wondering if what is your suggestion?

Comment: It says in the vignette, "If one would like to set the positions manually, one has to specify a list of matrices P in the argument list.". Wow dude I have no idea what is being plotted so I cannot guess what matrix P should be...